# How to create tar file in Elixir by Erlang

Tags: elixir

I tried several times to create directory to .tar archive. but I didn't succeed.

Example code for creating .tar format. (with erlang)

```
{:ok , filename } = File.ls("/Users/shahryar/Desktop/test")
:erl_tar.create("test.tar", filename)
```

but my test had been failing.

Please help me to create archive file (.tar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erlang's `erl_tar.create/2` expects a list of charlists as the second argument, but you have passed a list of binaries instead. Try instead:

```
{:ok , filenames} = File.ls("/Users/shahryar/Desktop/test")
:ok = :erl_tar.create("test.tar", Enum.map(filenames, &to_charlist/1))
```

Understanding the difference between charlists and binaries is important, especially when you're dealing with Erlang libraries. Check the [official documentation](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html) for more information.

Comment: hi . At first time your code worked . but after reset iex , code have an error ```** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {'one', :enoent}}```

Comment: `:enoent` means the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Please see my Terminal pic  : [link](http://s9.picofile.com/file/8307181076/Screen_Shot_2017_09_23_at_7_26_09_am.png) . this file exists.

Comment: `File.ls` gives you relative file names. That means you either need to `cd` into the directory before running `iex`, or you need to turn the filenames into absolute filenames. For instance, try `abs_filenames = filenames |> Enum.map(&Path.join("/Users/shahryar/Desktop/test", &1)) |> Enum.map(&to_charlist/1)`, then use `abs_filenames` as the 2nd argument for `:erl_tar.create`.

Comment: Thank you . its work. i must cd to the file and run your cod.